# Putting Data From File To Char Array Doesn't Stop At Last Data

Tags: c++

I'm rusty on using classes and am brushing up on using them.  I've encountered a problem where I'm attempting to use a simple program to retrieve data from a file that holds a simple number ("1234" in this case).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class hold
{
public:
    void enter();
    hold();
private:
    char x[50];
}; 

 hold::hold()
{
    x[50] = NULL;
}

void hold::enter()
{
    std::ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("num.txt");
    int pos = 0;
    while(inFile.good())
    {
        inFile >> x[pos];
        pos++;
    }

    std::cout << "strlen(x) = " << strlen(x) << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(x); i++)
    {
        std::cout << x[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    hold h;
    h.enter();
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
strlen(x) = 50;
1 2 3 4 (following a bunch of signs I do not know how to print).
```

It's been almost a year since I've consistently practiced classes and I don't recall having used a character array in a class.  Can anyone tell me where I'm messing up with this file not terminating after "4"?  I've tried using if statements to break the while loop if "x[pos] == '\0', but it didn't work either.

Comment: Also, when I don't use a class, the function enter() works just fine.  Outputs "1 2 3 4" and stops.  strlen(x) will read the correct number.  Just when I use a class, it doesn't.

Comment: What do you think `strlen` does?

Comment: returns the number of character elements in the array

Comment: That is incorrect. But even if it was correct, the number of character elements in the array is always 50, so why wouldn't it print 50 characters?

Comment: Side note: `x[50]` is the 51st element of the array. But the array only has 50 elements. Therefore, undefined behaviour!

Answer (score 1):

You did not terminate your string and you have undefined behaviour because `strlen` is hitting elements of the array that were never initialised.  Try this:

```
while( pos < 49 && inFile >> x[pos] )
{
    pos++;
}
x[pos] = '\0';
```

Note that `pos` after the loop will now be the same as what is returned by `strlen(x)`.

If you don't need a null-terminated string, then just use `pos` instead of `strlen(x)` without terminating but in that case you will need to avoid using any string functions that rely on null-terminated strings.

You also have a stack-smashing problem (undefined behaviour) in your constructor:

```
hold::hold()
{
    x[50] = NULL;
}
```

This is not okay.  You are not allowed to modify memory past the end of the array.  If you want to zero it, you can just do

```
memset( x, 0, sizeof(x) );
```

Or in C++11:

```
hold::hold()
    : x{ 0 }
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked; however, after I run it on Microsoft Visual Studio, I get a warning:  "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'h' was corrupted."  Is there a way to avoid that from appearing?

Comment: Well, yeah...  Did you remove the undefined behaviour from your constructor like I suggested?  Writing off the end of the array would totally explain that run-time check failure.

Comment: Yes I did and that fixed it.  I had missed that part of your comment when I first read it (didn't scroll down).  Saw it after I had posted my question and had one of those moments of "why didn't I just scroll down" type of things.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` expects a null-terminated string. Since your `x` is *not* null-terminated, passing it to `strlen` is [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Fortunately, you do not need to call `strlen`, because you have variable `pos` that counts the number of active entries inside `x`:

```
std::cout << "length of my string = " << pos << std::endl;
for(int i = 0; i < pos ; i++) {
    std::cout << x[i] << " ";
}
```

> Is there a way to account for that extra character other than `pos-1`?

Yes, a better way is to increment `pos` only when you know that character input has been successful:

```
while(inFile >> x[pos]) {
    pos++;
}
```

Comment: I had only used strlen to check the number of characters x held.  When I used strlen in an independent function (not sure of the term as I'm typing now) it always gave me back the number of items I had, like "1234" would return 4.  That's the only reason I was using it.  But as I'm learning a lot from these responses.  Thank you.

Comment: When I use just pos in the condition, it prints out just one more weird looking character.  With " pos -1", it prints like paddy suggested.  Is there a way to account for that extra character other than "pos -1"?  Or is "pos -1" the best approach?